# Uilabel height using boundigRect

Tags: ios, swift, string, uilabel

Hi everyone I have created a view that shows an error message. Within this view I have inserted a `UILabel` that shows the message. So far so good, the height of the `UILabel` changes based on the length of the text using `text.boundingRect`

My problem is that the text is shown correctly only if it does not exceed a certain number of lines, in case the text is too long it is cut and I don't understand why

In short, if the text is not very long I have no display problems otherwise if the text is very long it is cut

this is what i am using to get the height of the text.

Where am I wrong?

```
private func estimateTextHeight()-> CGFloat {
        let text = (toastView.textLbl.text ?? "") as NSString
        let attribute: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.font: toastView.textLbl.font!]
        return text.boundingRect(with: .init(width: 300, height: 2000), options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attribute, context: nil).height
    }

 private func updateToast(icon: UIImage?) -> Void {
        let height = estimateTextHeight() 

        toastView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height).isActive = true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To calculate label height try this:

```
 extension String {
    func height(withConstrainedWidth width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width,
                                    height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect,
                                            options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
                                            attributes: [.font: font],
                                            context: nil)
        return ceil(boundingBox.height)
    }
}
```